# How to get the date the case was viewed

Tags: case, omnichannel

Is there a way to get the date viewed of the case just like the lead's standard facility of read and unread.

I am using omni channel but cases can also be manually picked from the queue.

Answer (score 1):

if you read the Case objects [Soap Api documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_case.htm), there are 2 fields that might interest you:

- LastReferencedDate
- LastViewedDate

you can validate with the following SOQL:

```
select id, LastViewedDate, LastReferencedDate, CaseNumber, Subject
 from Case
```

and this will return a date in the following format per case record:

> 2017-04-13T19:36:40.000+0000